# linux environmental variable diff

Tags: linux, shell

I have two Linux xterms with "almost" the same setup. One setup works and the other doesn't for my application.

Is there a tool that can help me figure out which particular environment variable is causing the failure? (A visual diff)

Currently - I do

```
env > a1
env > a2
```

in the 2 xterms and do a diff on them.

But would like to know if there is a tool which can help me save some time. Thanks

Comment: meld is good for visualizing diffs http://meld.sourceforge.net/ also k3diff

Comment: What's wrong with your existing solution? It looks perfectly reasonable. To make it more robust you might consider sorting the output `env | sort > a1`.

Comment: It would help if you said what particular way your code was failing.

Answer (score 1):

Putting together the comments of @msw and @Adam Byrtek (which I voted up) we get something like the following. Note that diff has a --side-by-side option that works well if you don't have X:

```
a1 $ env | sort > a1
a2 $ env | sort > a2
#somehow get the files on the same host

a2 $ meld a1 a2
# or, in a terminal setting
a2 $ diff --side-by-side a1 a2
```

Things to look for are PATH, LD_PRELOAD, and any APP vars like JAVA_HOME, PYTHON_PATH, or RUBYPATH.

Answer (score 0):

For me, the hard part was handling newlines in some of my environment variables.  So I used null bytes to delimit the variables:

```
a1 $ env -0 | sort -z | tr "\0" "\n" > /tmp/a1.env
a2 $ env -0 | sort -z | tr "\0" "\n" > /tmp/a2.env
a2 $ diff /tmp/a1.env /tmp/a2.env
```

The sorting is to help diff match up the variables.

Answer (score 0):

Difference between two envs ( env & bundle exec env) could be found like this:

```
diff <(env) <(bundle exec env)
```

if we have folder with .env file in it, and we want to know difference in envs between using this dotenv file or without it:

```
diff <(bundle exec env) <(export $(egrep -v '^#' .env | xargs) && bundle exec env)
```